# How to create a function that selectively deletes a div based on its ID

Tags: javascript, html

For my program, i have a button that append's newly created div to the page and sequentially names these new divs in the sequence of MydivIDis1, MydivIDis2, MydivIDis3 and so on. Each of these newly created divs will have a 'delete' button. The delete button will delete the div that it is currently in. However, i do not know how to do this.

In the code below, i have tried to use javascript to create a "remove element" button within each div. The button is tied to an onclick function called remove. I have also specified in the button.onclick to take in the argument newDiv.id. This code is not working however.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="MainContainer">
    <input type="button" value="Add Element" id="add" onClick="add();">
    <div id="InnerContainer">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var mainDiv=document.getElementById("MainContainer");
var innerDiv=document.getElementById("InnerContainer");
var clicks=0

var add=function(){
    clicks += 1;

    var newDiv=document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.id="MydivIDis"+clicks;
    newDiv.innerHTML=newDiv.id

    mainDiv.appendChild(newDiv); //creates the new Div, with the id MydivIDis1, MydivIDis2, MydivIDis3 

    var button=document.createElement("button");
    var t=document.createTextNode("Remove Element");
    button.onclick=function(){
        remove(newDiv.id); //Here i am trying to specify to the program to take newDiv.id as the input to the remove function.
    };

    button.appendChild(t); //creates new button and appends to each new Div

    var remove=function(input){
        mainDiv.removeChild(input);
    }

    mainDiv.appendChild(button);
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) seems to take a node as an argument instead of an ID. So the solution might just be to change `remove(newDiv.id)` to `remove(newDiv)`.

Comment: Right. I'll post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

[`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) takes a node as an argument instead of an element ID.

So the solution is to just give `newDiv` to the `remove` function.

```
button.onclick=function(){
    remove(newDiv);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your remove statement is wrong, remove element like this

```
 mainDiv.removeChild(document.getElementById(input));
```

Also, as per your current design even after removing the `div` the remove button will still be there, if you want to remove that button also you have to replace this line

```
mainDiv.appendChild(button);
```

With this

```
newDiv.appendChild(button);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your feedback. Both your method and sevanteri's method works.

Comment: Cool! It you feel it worked for you please mark the answer correct! :)

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just use jQuery?
It's an awesome library.
Just give an ID to the div tag you want to alter and remove it.  I'll give you an example on using it.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").remove();
  }
```

Comment: Hi, sorry. I am taking up a course in javascript and want to familiarise myself entirely with this language, thats why i rather not use JQuery yet.